# How to update a permalink

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have this html link

```
<span>
    ( <a id="permalink" href="path/">Permalink</a> )
</span>
```

I want to have an update method but its in javascript. How do I make my paralink link get updated whenever the javascript method gets changed.

```
function permalink()
{
    var book= getbook();

    var permalink = document.getElementById("permalink");

    permalink.href ="Book="book;
}
```

I want now my orignal path that was in:

```
<span>
    ( <a id="permalink" href="path/">Permalink</a> )
</span>
```

to contain path/book

In my output my permalink still only displays the path and not book

function permalink() { var book= getbook(); var permalink = document.getElementById("permalink"); permalink.href +='Book='+book; }

It is not changing my original permalink link:  ( Permalink )  That link is not changing

Comment: Your actual question is "how do I concatenate two strings", and your attempt is `permalink.href ="Book="book;`. The answer is with "+". `"Book=" + book`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what the value of `getbook();` will return or what you actually want your url, but using `+=` will append what you give it to the existing `href` attribute.

`permalink.href += 'book/' + book;`

Here is an example that works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/edhedges/7rd8P/

html markup:

```
<span>
    ( <a id="permalink" href="path/">Permalink</a> )
</span>

<button onclick="permalink()">Change Permalink</button>
```

js code:
    function getbook() {
        return 'EndersGame';
    }

```
function permalink()
{
    var book= getbook();
    var permalink = document.getElementById("permalink");
    permalink.href += 'book/' + book;
}
```

Click the button and see the link change

Comment: In my output my permalink still only displays the path and not book

Comment: function permalink()
{
    var book= getbook();

    var permalink = document.getElementById("permalink");

    permalink.href +='Book='+book;
}

Comment: It is not changing my original permalink link: 

<span>
    ( <a id="permalink" href="path/">Permalink</a> )
</span>

That link is not changing